# How to resolve false-positive sonar warning 'Add some tests to this class'

Tags: java, sonarqube, testng

I am using Sonar 5.2 to analyze java project, tests written in TestNG.
I have test classes with @Test annotation on the class (not on methods).

My tests are working fine (testNG treats all public methods as tests, no @Test annotation is required on each method), but sonar produces warning

> TestCases should contain tests (squid:S2187)

If I put @Test annotation on methods, this warning disappears.

It looks to me like false-positive (My class has test methods).
For testNG tests, squid:S2187 rule should be ignored if class has @Test annotation on class level and at least one public method.

Is this indeed bug in squid:S2187 rule, or I am missing something?

Edit:
I am using Sonar 5.2, java plugin 3.7
At the time of the writing (10 November 2015) my Sonar is up-to-date.

Comment: Can you please precise the version of sonar-java-plugin you are using ?

Comment: This is indeed a false positive, it is going to be fixed in version 3.8 of the sonar java plugin.
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1373

Comment: Is it possible that this behaviour is present again? I'm using SonarQube 6.0 and Java Plugin 4.2. Also interesting: SonarLint in IntelliJ IDEA works correctly and shows the warning only if I remove the `@Test` annotation from the class for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use annotation `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2187")`